# What is causing my patches to cover my turtles?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have been following the tutorial listed here [Netlogo tutorial pt3](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/tutorial3.html#patches-and-variables)

In the section "Patches and variables" I simply do not observe the image shown when I followed the steps exactly.

[image]

Instead, I can only see a green cube with my agents seemingly stuck inside.

What am I missing here? My word is only a single cube.

[image]

These are the routines that I've copied from the tutorial that should show turtles scattered across the green patch.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 100
  ask turtles [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
end


to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
end
```

Comment: Hey it looks like you're running the code in NetLogo 3D, but that tutorial is written for NetLogo 2D.  If you ran the code in 2D I think it'd work as you expect.  I see you also found a workaround to get it working in 3D as well, per your answer, but wanted to make sure you were aware in case you check out more of the tutorials on the site.

Answer (score 2):

[image]It turns out the tutorial omits to tell you that you need to set the max-pzcor value in model settings to zero for this to work.